# running a Unit test from irb or pry

Tags: ruby, testing, irb, pry

Is there a way to run a testfile from inside an irb or pry session?

I tried `load './testfile.rb`, but that doesn't run the tests in the testfile.

My Testfile looks like this:

```
require 'test/unit'
require './sudoku.rb'

class SudokuTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_initialize
    assert_nothing_raised do
      Sudoku.new(Array.new(9*9))
    end
    assert_nothing_raised do
      Sudoku.new(Array.new(9*9,Field.new(nil)))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tests are not really meant to be run interactively like that, but if you look in the ruby standard library and look at the file `test/unit.rb` you will see that it sets an `at_exit` handler when you `require 'test/unit'`:

```
at_exit do
  unless $! || Test::Unit.run?
    Kernel.exit Test::Unit::AutoRunner.run
  end
end
```

So looking at this all you need to do in your `irb` session is call:

```
Test::Unit::AutoRunner.run
```

This will run all tests you have loaded that are subclassed from `Test::Unit::TestCase`.

If you just want to run the test file, without loading it into the `irb` session, you could simply do:

```
system 'ruby testfile.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't run the tests because you aren't asking it for. You're just *creating* the class.

Try this:

```
tests = SudokuTest.new
tests.test_initialize
```

Comment: If I try this I get: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` when calling SudokuTest.new and I can't figure out what it actually wants as an argument.

Comment: The argument should be the method's that should be tested: http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/Test/Unit/TestCase.html#method-c-new. Try simply `SudokuTest.new :test_initialize`.

Comment: Using `SudokuTest.new :test_initialize` creates a SudokuTest object, but calling `test_initialize` on it gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method 'add_assertion' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [plymouth](https://github.com/banister/plymouth) is what you want. It can start a Pry session automatically in the context of a failing test.